# Rotational kinematics of a non-rigid body. Equation of motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

Two masses (of mass $m$) $1$ and $2$ are mounted on a massless rod. Mass $1$ is firmly bolted to the rod, mass $2$ can slide without friction along the rod.

At $t=0$ the system is brought into rotation about the centre of mass (CoM) at angular velocity $\omega_0$. No external forces act on the system.

[image: Rotation non-rigid body]

Because there's no centripetal force acting on $2$, it will move away from $1$.

But with no external forces acting on the system, the CoM must remain stationary (immobile).

The question is, *how does the separation $R$ between $1$ and $2$ evolve in time?*

Firstly, applying conservation of rotational kinetic energy:

$$\frac12 I_0\omega_0^2=\frac12 I\omega^2$$
$$mR_0^2\omega_0^2=mR^2\omega^2$$
Taking the time derivative of the Hamiltonian should give us the Newtonian equation of motion:
$$(R^2\omega^2)'=0$$
$$2(R\omega)'=0$$
$$\dot{R}\omega+R\dot{\omega}=0\tag{1}$$
Now apply conservation of momentum:
$$L_0=L(t)$$
$$I_0\omega_0=I\omega$$
$$2mR_0^2\omega_0=2mR^2\omega$$
$$\omega=R_0^2\omega_0 R^{-2}$$
$$\dot{\omega}=-2R_0^2\omega_0R^{-3}\dot{R}$$

I'm not used to dealing with non-rigid bodies, so where am I conceptually going wrong?

---

I believe *looksquirrel101* is correct. The full Hamiltonian should be:

$$\frac14 mR^2\omega^2+2\times \frac12 m \Big(\frac{\dot{R}}{2}\Big)^2=\frac14 mR_0^2\omega_0^2+2\times \frac12 m \Big(\frac{\dot{R_0}}{2}\Big)^2$$
or:

$$R^2\omega^2+\dot{R}^2=R_0^2\omega_0^2+\dot{R_0}^2$$
Using the expression for $\omega$:

$$\omega=R_0^2\omega_0 R^{-2}$$
$$R^2 R_0^4\omega_0^2 R^{-4}+\dot{R}^2=R_0^2\omega_0^2+\dot{R_0}^2$$
$$ R_0^4\omega_0^2 R^{-2}+\dot{R}^2=R_0^2\omega_0^2+\dot{R_0}^2$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117914/discussion-on-question-by-gert-rotational-kinematics-of-a-non-rigid-body-equati).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conservation of energy equation is incomplete. The masses don't only have a velocity component perpendicular to the rod, but also along the direction of the rod. You need to include those components of velocity in your conservation of energy equation.

Comment: Ah yes. I think you're correct. Well spotted.

Answer (score 1):

I see no indication of radii for the masses.  If treated as point masses with no friction, they exert no force or torque on each other.  Each will move off on a straight line with their initial tangential velocities. If you choose an x axis through the position of the two masses at t = 0, and the y axis through the CoM, then: mass 2, will have coordinates (R/2, (R/2)$ω_o$t).  It's position vector will have a magnitude, r, and the separation of the two masses will be, 2r.

Comment: Yes, they're point masses.